# Book series about a girl who wakes up with a tattoo on her birthday and it gives her powers

Tags: story-identification, powers

When I was younger I read a book about a teen girl who was an orphan who started to attend an academy that only a few people were allowed to attend because when the students turned a certain age they would wake up with a tattoo that would give you powers. I remember the girl had two love interests and one was depicted as bad and another had a girlfriend at the time. But turns out that the bad guy was actually good in the end and one had the ability to shape shift. When she got her tattoo it was bigger than anyone else's and it was sparkly. Her power was the ability to copy other people's power. And during the book there was a costume party and she dressed up as Tinker Bell.

This was a long book so I thought a was a standalone not part of a series. At one point in the book she finds out that one of her parents had a fire ability and their house got burned or something like that and that's how they died and her father was really powerful. And she met her brother or step brother who had a similar ability which was to steal people's abilities or something like that. It turns out he's a bad guy and they fight and he takes all the abilities she had accumulated but ends up helping her towards the end. Also when she was at the academy when she had no idea about the tattoos she had gotten in trouble and as punishment she had to clean up the graveyard that was behind the school and when she was talking to one of her love interests a statue fell and was going to squash her but the guy dived and got her out of the way in time.

Also at one point she met the queen or princess of England who used to be a part of the academy whose power was to understand and speak and write every language. I think the academy gave the students missions but I'm not entirely sure. Also towards the end the girl and her friends are being stalked or something and they find a picture book and they all look like they have matured and grown up a bit except her. She looks the same in every picture and they find a locked room and they bust it open and it is covered in pictures of her and turns out she was a project and the stalker guy had made her immortal and that's how the first book ends.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Nice question, lots of detail, but when (what year) did you read this?

Comment: Similar question
here  https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/263975/book-series-about-a-girl-who-wakes-up-on-her-sixteenth-birthday-with-tattoos-tha/263979#263979

Answer (score 6):

Could this be the [Chronicles of Kerrigan](https://www.goodreads.com/series/74270-the-chronicles-of-kerrigan) series, starting with [Rae of Hope](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/12720979-rae-of-hope), by W J May?

The first book has the description:

> Fifteen year-old Rae Kerrigan never really knew her family's history. Her mother and father died when she was young and it is only when she accepts a scholarship to the prestigious Guilder Boarding School in England that a mysterious family secret is revealed.
>
> Will the sins of the father be the sins of the daughter?
>
> As Rae struggles with new friends, a new school and a star-struck forbidden love, she must also face the ultimate challenge: receive a tattoo on her sixteenth birthday with specific powers that may bind her to an unspeakable darkness. It's up to Rae to undo the dark evil in her family's past and have a ray of hope for her future.

And with reference to meeting the queen of England, [the fourth book's](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/24587759-royal-tea) description has:

> The Queen of England has requested the help of the Privy Council. Someone is trying to kill her son’s fiancé. The HRH Prince plans to marry a commoner, and his bride has a secret no one knows but the Privy Council. She has a tatù. When the Privy Council turns to Rae for help, she can’t possibly say no; not even when they make Devon her partner for this assignment. They are to pose as a couple and work undercover, as bodyguards, to protect the soon to be Princess of Wales.